# High CPU usage after hostname change

Tags: 12.04, cpu-load, init, vps

I have a Ubuntu 12.04.4 64bit installation (running as an OpenVZ container) that was running fairly well until I changed the hostname.

The change was made just by modifying `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`, and restarting the network. After that, load avg increased a lot (normally was 0.3 and now stays constantly at 2.5)

If I use some tool like `htop` or `top` the only process that I can see with some cpu usage is `init` (always between 10 and 15 percent).

I tried to strace init to try to get some clue, but I always get the same error:

```
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

and I cant change that key also.

I cant find anything in syslog so I am completely clueless here. Has anyone faced a similar situation or has any tips on how to debug this problem? If really needed, a restart can be performed but I would prefer to not do that.

Comment: What process do you try to trace? This sometimes happens when in-kernel drivers go nuts, you don't see 'em in `top`. Also, system load is different from CPU load, perhaps there's a lot of I/O... Try `iotop -o` and see if something shows up.

Comment: Sorry for just answering now. I tried to trace `init` because it was the only one showing some abnormal activity. I think this may be something related to OpenVZ/upstart. I was forced to reboot the system in the meantime and everything got normal again. Either way if you have any tips on how to debug a problem like this please post them as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It would at first guess be something that when installed copied the hostname into it's configuration file and is now having problems with the machine renamed.

I would `grep -iR oldhostname /etc` and see if that gives a clue.

Also, just to check you did actually reboot after changing the hostname? If not then you should if possible do so because running processes initialised with the old hostname. If a reboot isn't feasible you could try reloading affected processes if you can identify them but I've not personally tried that approach.

Finally, `atop` is a very useful tool for problem identification as it gives a comprehensive overview of the system, cpu, memory, network, drives etc. It often helps to narrow down the affected area and then you use a more specific tool if needed to zoom in on the problem.